# Syntax Highlighting for go in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, go, syntax-highlighting

Ok so I have been making a simple code editor in vb.net for go.. (for personal uses)
I tried this code -

```
Dim tokens As String = "(break|default|func|interface|select|case|defer|go|map|struct|chan|else|goto|package|switch|const|fallthrough|if|range|type|continue|for|import|return|var)"
        Dim rex As New Regex(tokens)
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = rex.Matches(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim StartCursorPosition As Integer = TextBox2.SelectionStart
        For Each m As Match In mc
            Dim startIndex As Integer = m.Index
            Dim StopIndex As Integer = m.Length
            TextBox2.[Select](startIndex, StopIndex)
            TextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204)
            TextBox2.SelectionStart = StartCursorPosition

            TextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.RebeccaPurple
        Next
```

but I couldn't add something like print statements say I want a fmt.Println("Hello World"), that is not possible, anyone help me?

I want a simple result that will do proper syntax without glitching text colors like this current code does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code showing how to update highlighting with strings and numbers.
You would need to tweak it further to support syntax like comments, etc.

```
private Regex BuildExpression()
{
    string[] exprs = { 
        "(break|default|func|interface|select|case|defer|go|map|struct|chan|else|goto|package|switch|const|fallthrough|if|range|type|continue|for|import|return|var)", 
        @"([0-9]+\.[0-9]*(e|E)(\+|\-)?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([0-9]+)",
        "(\"\")|\"((((\\\\\")|(\"\")|[^\"])*\")|(((\\\\\")|(\"\")|[^\"])*))"
    };

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < exprs.Length; i++)
    {
        string expr = exprs[i];
        if ((expr != null) && (expr != string.Empty))
            sb.Append(string.Format("(?<{0}>{1})", "_" + i.ToString(), expr) + "|");
    }

    if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
    return new Regex(sb.ToString(), options);
}

private void HighlightSyntax()
{
    var colors = new Dictionary<int, Color>();

    var expression = BuildExpression();
    Color[] clrs = { Color.Teal, Color.Red, Color.Blue };
    int[] intarray = expression.GetGroupNumbers();
    foreach (int i in intarray)
    {
        var name = expression.GroupNameFromNumber(i);
        if ((name != null) && (name.Length > 0) && (name[0] == '_'))
        {
            var idx = int.Parse(name.Substring(1));
            if (idx < clrs.Length)
                colors.Add(i, clrs[idx]);
        }
    }

    foreach (Match match in expression.Matches(richTextBox1.Text))
    {
        int index = match.Index;
        int length = match.Length;
        richTextBox1.Select(index, length);
        for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            if (match.Groups[i].Success)
            {
                if (colors.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = colors[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What we found during development of our [Code Editor](https://www.alternetsoft.com/products/editor) libraries, is that the regular expression-based parsers are hard to adapt to fully support advanced syntax like contextual keywords (LINQ) or interpolated strings.

You might find a bit more information here:
https://www.alternetsoft.com/blog/code-parsing-explained

The most accurate syntax highlighting for VB.NET can be implemented using [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/) API, it's the same API used internally by Visual Studio text editor.
Below is sample code showing how to get classified spans for VB.NET code (every span contains start/end position within the text and classification type, i.e. keyword, string, etc.). These spans then can be used to highlight text inside a textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Classification;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

public class VBClassifier
{

    private Workspace workspace;

    private static string FileContent = @"
Public Sub Run()
    Dim test as TestClass = new TestClass()   
End Sub";

    public void Classify()
    {
        var project = InitProject();
        var doc = AddDocument(project, "file1.vb", FileContent);
        var spans = Classify(doc);
    }


    protected IEnumerable<ClassifiedSpan> Classify(Document document)
    {
        var text = document.GetTextAsync().Result;
        var span = new TextSpan(0, text.Length);
        return Classifier.GetClassifiedSpansAsync(document, span).Result;
    }

    protected Document AddDocument(Project project, string fileName, string code)
    {
        var documentId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(project.Id, fileName);

        ApplySolutionChanges(s => s.AddDocument(documentId, fileName, code, filePath: fileName));

        return workspace.CurrentSolution.GetDocument(documentId);
    }

    protected virtual void ApplySolutionChanges(Func<Solution, Solution> action)
    {
        var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
        solution = action(solution);
        workspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);
    }

    protected MefHostServices GetRoslynCompositionHost()
    {
        IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = MefHostServices.DefaultAssemblies;
        var compositionHost = MefHostServices.Create(assemblies);

        return compositionHost;
    }

    protected Project CreateDefaultProject()
    {
        var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
        var projectId = ProjectId.CreateNewId();
        var projectName = "VBTest";

        ProjectInfo projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(
            projectId,
            VersionStamp.Default,
            projectName,
            projectName,
            LanguageNames.VisualBasic,
            filePath: null);

        ApplySolutionChanges(s => s.AddProject(projectInfo));

        return workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected Project InitProject()
    {
        var host = GetRoslynCompositionHost();
        workspace = new AdhocWorkspace(host);

        return CreateDefaultProject();
    }
}
```

Update:
Here's a Visual Studio project demonstrating both approaches:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LLuzy7yDFAE-v40I7EswECYQSthxheEf/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: But I made the app with winforms and this code doesnt work..

Comment: I've just added a link to the VisualStudio project in my original reply